# Join multiple columns from multiple variables?

Tags: command-line, variable, join

var $abc contains:

```
abc  jkl
def  mno
ghi  pqr
```

var $def contains:

```
stu
vwx
yz
```

Expected output:

```
abc  jkl  stu
def  mno  vwx
ghi  pqr  yz
```

**heemayl**'s solution:

I tried `paste <(echo "$abc") <(echo "$def")` but it is giving output as below

```
ASFSFGFGGRRFDFFFFFH     33566
AHSHDFFBORDASHFYEHFYUCH 33568
FASFSSFHJUYRT   33371
FASIFIDFGGGDDDDD        33364
AFDDDGGGGGDER   33371
FDGGGGHJJK      16225
AISJFKDJFKDDKFJKDJFF    33568
KDFJKDJFKDJFKDFJK       33567
```

How to align the second column correctly?

Solution:

```
paste <(echo "$abc") <(echo "$def") | column -t
```

Comment: Just a general note: Don't store the contents of files in variables. It is very seldom needed, and it's more error-prone to work with than just reading directly from the output of a command or from a file.

Comment: @Kusalananda So if I would need say only first column from a file, i usually do awk '{print $1}' and save it in a variable, and then use it further. How else can we do it if not store it in a variable?

Comment: See the question that your question is marked as a duplicate of.  Using `paste <( command_used_for_abc ) <( command_for_def )` would solve it for you. `command_for_abc` might, for example be `awk '{ print $1 }' somefilename`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `paste`, with help from process substitution to get two file descriptors for `paste` to operate on:

```
paste <(echo "$abc") <(echo "$def")
```

Be careful with the quoting of the variables.

**Example:**

```
$ echo "$abc"
abc jkl
def mno
ghi pqr

$ echo "$def"
stu
vwx
yz

$ paste <(echo "$abc") <(echo "$def")
abc jkl stu
def mno vwx
ghi pqr yz
```

Comment: It works! However I need to format the output to display the second column correctly. I have updated the question with an example. How do we fix this?

Comment: @Koshur Tack `column`: `paste <(echo "$abc") <(echo "$def") | column -t`

Comment: Is there a way to redirect this output to a CSV or Excel file?

Comment: @Koshur Use a CSV then: `paste ... | sed 's/[[:blank:]]\+/,/g'` (assuming no native comma in any field)